# Can I use Ethernet and Wi-Fi on different application?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet

I have 2 internet connections - LTE from my mobile operator (with data limits) and normal internet with Wi-Fi. Now I need to download large files (~15GB). Wi-Fi internet sure is better option for this since it's unlimited.

I would like to set my download manager to use Wi-Fi connection and internet browser to use LTE connection, so I can surf the internet without throttling download speed. Is something like that possible?

Comment: It's possible at some level. but most OS-es don't make it all that accessible/easy. Then again, if it's a minor amount of data for browsing, it's a minor amount of data to "impact" your downloading.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Is it possible on Ubuntu? I also have a hunch that it should be possible with VirtualBox, but I'm not sure how to configure guest to use Wi-Fi connection only. And I don't want to throttle my Wi-Fi connection by browsing because it's painfully slow already (~4.5mbps).

Comment: For Linux, have a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface).

Comment: Sorry my bad. For Linux, try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox method for Ubuntu 14.04 (probably works even in other OSs, but I can't guarantee that):

1. Connect to desired connection for host first (in my case LTE)
2. Connect to second connection (in my case Wi-Fi)
   *Now you are connected to both LTE and Wi-Fi internet, but host will automatically use connection that was established first. So despite being connected to both LTE and Wi-Fi, only LTE is being used*
3. Run VirtualBox, right-click virtual machine of your choice, click **Settings**, go to **Network** category, set adapter to **Bridged** and choose **wlan0** (or whatever name your wireless adapter has)
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xVR.png)

Done! Now every application run in VM will use only Wi-Fi connection, while host will be using LTE internet only.

---

*Note: I'm pretty sure on Unix based systems there's `iptables` method, which consists of allowing different users to use only different connections, but I have no enough knowledge with `iptables` to do that. So if somebody knows how to work it out, I will be very thankful for answer.*

Answer (score 1):

Try [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip)

ForceBindIP binds any Windows application to a specific interface or IP address.

Comment: This might be a good solution for Windows users, but I use Ubuntu